# Missing controls using Angular2 Reactive Forms

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

**Edit:** fixed button per discussion below. However, unless I'm misunderstanding something, the data structure connected to the form is not being updated. Also edited the first para and replaced images.

I'm running into a strange error with Angular2 and FormBuilder. The example I've put together has first name, last name fields along with a submit button. However, changed values are not submitted via the data structure. Here is a screen shot:
[image: FormBuileder with Material]

It's not caused by Material, however. Removing Material directives:
[image]

I'm baffled why this apparently simple form fails. Suggestions?

**app.component.html:**

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="onSubmit()" >
  <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName" required >
      <div class="error" *ngIf="myForm.get('firstName').touched && myForm.get('firstName').hasError('required')">
        First Name is required
      </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastName" required >
      <div class="error" *ngIf="myForm.get('lastName').touched && myForm.get('lastName').hasError('required')">
        Last Name is required
      </div>
   </md-input-container>
   <div>
        <button type="submit" md-raised-button>Submit</button>
   </div>

</form>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

interface Name {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
//  templateUrl: './app.component2.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'Using FormBuilder';
  myForm: FormGroup;
  data: Name;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.data = this.loadData();
    this.myForm = this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnDestroy () {

  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("name=", JSON.stringify(this.data));
  }

  private loadData(): Name {
    const result: Name = <Name>{
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    }

    return result;
  }

  private createForm(): FormGroup {
    const result: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      "firstName": [this.data.firstName, [Validators.required]],
//      "lastName": [this.data.lastName, [Validators.required, MyValidators.validateName]]
      "lastName": [this.data.lastName, [Validators.required]]
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button should be class=" md-raised-button"

Comment: According to the current Material document, nope. Please see the examples at https://material.angular.io/components/component/button

Comment: You'll have to  `import {MdButtonModule} from '@angular/material';` if you want to use it without the class call.

Comment: Already have `MdButtonModule` imported. It turns out `<button>` with `md-raised-button` or `class="md-raised-button"` generates a button, but without Material styling. The reason these buttons don't appear is operator error - when I was creating a cut-down example, I forgot the `value=` to name the button. So without Material it should be `<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`. For Material, `<button type="submit" md-raised-button>Submit</button>`.

Comment: However, with the button visible, the form doesn't seem to sending updated field values. This was cut down from a much larger form, so I'll take another look at that.